# Applications in OSX Yosemite independently freeze then execute simultaneously

Tags: macos, performance

I have ample storage on my hard drive and 8GB RAM and have serious freezing issues, even doing things as simple as running Chrome. Seems to happen when I'm doing something new (e.g. pausing a Youtube video, opening a new tab, changing volume). Another example, in MS Word, I'll be typing, see no words appear, continue typing, then all of a sudden everything appears at once and runs well. The app becomes nonresponseive, but I can still move the window.

Has anyone experienced this or have any suggestions?

Much appreciated!

Comment: first guess would be failing hard drive.  when you select the drive in Disk Utility what SMART Status do you see?

Comment: second guess is that something uses a lot of CPU and third guess something has heavy disk activity. Do you see anything with /Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app ? (make sure you see all processes and set the update time to 1 second to see as much as possible) [ sorry, my English is bad ]

Comment: Open /Utilities/Application Monitor and click on the % CPU header to sort heavy use CPU processes to the top. Comment back with the name(s) of the two 2 or 3 processes.

Comment: I only see Disk Status: Online. Top CPU processes include: Window Server, kernel_task, Google chrome (but keep switching around)

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem with my Mac Mini as well. I'm running with 10 gigs ran and just recently Secure wiped the entire disk and started over. Do you have this problem with safari? With the most recent glitchiness I have decided to try out Safari and it runs a whole lot smoother over there compared to Chrome.

Also are you using a disk drive or a solid-state drive in your Mac? I have a disk drive and I believe that's one reason why the Applications have been running a lot slower because whenever chrome is open it will attempt to cache its way all the way through your RAM no matter how much you have (recently I saw a complaint in a forum showing chrome had taken up 56 GB of their Mac pros ram). When chrome does this, you end up getting pushed into the swap area on your disk where disk drives really do struggle.

My guess for MS Word: Now that most of the modern machines or using solid-state drives, Developers are starting to safely assume that the user most likely will be using this as well and start sending resources back to the hard drive instead of RAM so they have more room to work with. This new method slows everything down as well if you're using a disk drive.

Comment: I have this problem with any application I'm running. Even if everything is closed and I'm just in the finder...

Comment: However I am using a disk drive. Any ideas on things I should try?

Comment: Do you happen to have a ton of stuff on the desktop or a lot of folders on the dock?

Comment: No, running very few applications...

Comment: Are you using advanced dictation? How old is the hard drive? And as a side note, do keep in mind that 8gb is the minimum ram in the latest macs.

Comment: Not old, replaced 1 year ago... RAM is new too. Do you think it could be a virus?

Comment: As long as you weren't completely careless with what you installed, it shouldn't be. Since you ask that, do you have a heavy antivirus running? The only antivirus I've ever used which both worked and didn't suck up all of my resources was Avast.